# Extract file from http response in Azure logic app

Tags: azure, azure-functions, httpresponse, azure-logic-apps, html-content-extraction

I have an Azure function (http triggered) which returns a CSV file in response. I am calling this function from a logic app using http request action (since I need to pass authentication details) and getting the http response with the CSV in body. Now I want to send this CSV as an attachment with an outlook email. Unfortunately I'm unable to do this. If I use the body of http response then the email body contains the full content of the CSV, whereas I want this as an attachment.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
SB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I solved.

Here is my sample Azure function and Logic app configuration

```
[FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static IActionResult Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
            var csvFile = new StringBuilder();
            csvFile.AppendLine(string.Format("{0},{1}", "1", "ABC"));
            csvFile.AppendLine(string.Format("{0},{1}", "2", "ABcd"));
            csvFile.AppendLine(string.Format("{0},{1}", "3", "ABCde"));
            csvFile.AppendLine(string.Format("{0},{1}", "4", "ABCdef"));
            csvFile.AppendLine(string.Format("{0},{1}", "5", "ABCdefg"));
            csvFile.AppendLine(string.Format("{0},{1}", "6", "ABCdefgh"));
            return new OkObjectResult(csvFile.ToString());
        }
```

[image]

Let us know if this works for you..we can do same with outlook account..I just used gmail account.

Comment: My bad. I did the same thing but didn't specify the attachment name. It works after specifying the filename. Thanks for the answer.